# How to get entityreference_backreference data programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

The User profile for my site contains the Entity Reference field 'Parent' which points to another User.

I have the `entityreference_backreference` module enabled on my Drupal 7 site.
I need to programmatically access the values of the properties added to the user entity by the `entityreference_backreference` module, so that for User A, I can identify all other Users which point to A via the 'Parent' EntityReference field.

If I do the following

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("user",$some_user);
$wrapper->getPropertyInfo();
```

I can see that that an entry for the entityreference_backreference field **field_parent_user_eb** is available in the `getPropertyInfo()` output. So the property does exist.

However, if I do

```
$wrapper->get('field_parent_user_eb');
```

it comes back with "data = null".

Also if I just try to access `$some_user->field_parent_user_eb` that also gives a null result.

It looks like the property is never being set.

What am I doing wrong? I can see that there is a "*getter callback*" defined for the **field_parent_user_eb** property, which is set to `entityreference_backreference_related_entities`, but I can't see how I can use this.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was my ignorance of how to use Entity Metadata Wrappers.
The way to get the value of the **field_parent_user_eb** field is

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("user",$some_user);
$value = $wrapper->field_parent_user_eb->value();
```

`$value` contains an array of entities which (back) reference the original `$some_user`.

I should have read https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers before posting.